# HAProxy hostname or URL backend

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to set up backend as Hostnames or URLs?

I want to use haproxy to balance both http and https requests to a pool of backends (TCP mode).

Since backends can change their IPs, I want to set backend servers as URLs.

```
...
defaults
    mode                    tcp
    option                  redispatch
    ...

frontend  all 
    bind *:80
    bind *:443
    option tcplog

    # DEFAULT
    default_backend         hostname_servers

backend hostname_severs
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server  host1     host1.myapp.com      check
    server  host2     host2.myapp.com      check
    ...
    server  hostN     hostN.myapp.com      check
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that functionality is now available in 1.6, http://blog.haproxy.com/2015/10/14/whats-new-in-haproxy-1-6/

From Link:

```
resolvers docker
nameserver dnsmasq 127.0.0.1:53

defaults
mode http
log global
option httplog

frontend f_myapp
bind :80
default_backend b_myapp

backend b_myapp
server s1 nginx1:80 check resolvers docker resolve-prefer ipv4
```